# "Empty test suite" by running Django tests with Pycharm (tests are found if launched from the shell)

Tags: python, django, unit-testing, pycharm

I'm having an hard time trying to run my **Django** tests using **PyCharm**.
I did it easily in the past using a "python running configuration" in which I used `manage.py` to run them, I was on OSX and using python 2.7, Django <= 1.7, Pycharm <= 4.
Now I'm on Linux Mint, I use Python 3.4.3, Django 1.8.2 and Pycharm 4.5.
I always used virtualenv to manage my projects.
Now by running "manage.py test" from Pycharm no tests are found (it prints "Empty test suite").
But tests exist, and if I run the command from the shell they get executed.
So I really don't understand what's going on.
I'm actually able to launch tests using "an hack" I created, but the problem is that Pycharm is not able to attach to the process in order to allow breakpoints in tests (which is one of the features I use the most!).
My "hack" is the following:

I created a python script with:

```
import subprocess


def main():
    subprocess.call('./venv_activator.sh', shell=True)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

then a bash script (`venv_activator.sh`):

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
source .ENV/bin/activate
python manage.py test myapp -p "*_tests.py" --noinput -v 2 --settings=settings.test
```

In practice the python script is used to create a "python running configuration" for Pycharm, then it activate the virtualenv and invokes the django test command.

ps: yes, I turned on "Django support" in PyCharm (and I configured the python interpreter under the virtualenv)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem is that PyCharm doesn't apply the given search pattern for test files (-p "*_tests.py"). It's a bug that has already been reported: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/PY-15869

The solution has been to simply rename my files :P

Answer (score 2):

Using pycharm, you can directly run your tests by creating a test configuration. Create a configuration using Run>Edit Configuration. Add a config from Django tests , set the virtual env path , working directory(path to manage.py), Target module (like complete_project or a complete_project.app_name).
Run the configuration , it will run the tests from the tests.py from corresponding module.

Comment: I know and I already tried that, but it doesn't work... it doesn't find tests

Comment: Every function must start with test, like test_articles.Have you also set the db configurations for test_db?Can you be any clear, as I have implemented and the unit testing is working just fine.

Comment: I know how tests should be named and, as I wrote, if I run tests from the shell (by running "python manage.py test myapp" once virtualenv is activated with "source .ENV/bin/activate") all works fine, so it's not a matter of how I wrote them or my django/python config... the problem is to understand what's the difference when using Pycharm run configuration... and the only one I can see is that virtualenv is not activated by Pycharm :P

Comment: Try setting python file path of the virtual environment in project interpreter in pycharm >> preferences >>project interpreter . like ~/Envs/MyVirtualenv/bin/python
 Hope this helps, if still a problem , I can tell it in more detail.

Comment: I already did that and I also added my project dir to $pythonpath :(

Comment: Then change the working directory to path of manage.py /Users/prateek/Projects/Myproj/ and target as the module to be tested, eg Myproj.myapp and for complete project Myproj

Comment: setting the right working directory it's among the very first things I've done :P ...it's unbelievable...I never had such problems before!

Comment: after all these settings are correct I am also not able to get , from where is the problem arising.

Answer (score 0):

For my case it was because the names of my test methods didn't start with `test`. Renamed them, and PyCharm started to run them correctly.