# PyCharm can't find Django test

Tags: python, django, pycharm

I'm running into this [very same issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30568207/empty-test-suite-by-running-django-tests-with-pycharm-tests-are-found-if-laun), but I can't find a solution for this.

Find the dummy Django project I created for this [here](https://copy.com/zSheDmEP17bBwMHq).

This is my test configuration:

[image]

This is the project structure:

[image]

Trying to run the test results in:

```
AttributeError: 'super' object has no attribute 'run_tests'

Process finished with exit code 137
Empty test suite.
```

Obviously, running this from the shell gives no errors:

```
(django)mosquito@mosquito-X550LD ~/python_projects/django_test $ python manage.py test 
Creating test database for alias 'default'...
.
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 1 test in 0.000s

OK
Destroying test database for alias 'default'...
```

Any idea what I'm doing wrong??

Thanks,
Alejandro

Comment: How is the structure of your app and test files I wonder.

Comment: Hello Wtower, is a simple hello, world app, you can check that by downloading the zip file

Comment: Will add an extra image to show the project structure, just in case

Answer (score 1):

In the project configuration, add another environment variable of

`DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE = django_test.settings`

You can do this by clicking on the "..." icon

Comment: Hello, I'm afraid that did not work either...same issue, I'm assuming you meant to add that variable in the debug/run configuration right?

Comment: That's correct. On the first image you uploaded there's the environment variables input, it would go in there. Also, is you virtualenv that's setup in pycharm correct? The name in the screenshot and the example shell outputs look different

Comment: Yeah, that's where I've set it up, check updated image, and the virtualenv are the same, I created a specifc one for the shell, but now I'm using the same one...

Comment: Yeah that all looks correct. What version of Django are you using and are you using "from django.test import TestCase" or are you importing TestCase from somewhere else?

Comment: DJango 1.8.1 here. And yes, I'm using from django.test import TestCase in the test class